# Interpolation resulting in nan

Tags: qgis, point, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate a point layer holding data of type double, I have gone back to older projects where I have successfully interpolated before and these don't work either (resulting in nan).

I have checked and the layers are of the same CRS, what doesn't make sense is the older project also not interpolating.

Is anyone else recently experiencing the same issue, if so have you managed to get around it?

Comment: Can you provide test data and specific steps to reproduce the issue?